# Sending multiple files in one post Request in HttpURLConnection in JAVA

Tags: java, file, post, httpurlconnection

I am sending files via post method using HttpURLConnection. I am sending with the file a parameter which is 'student_id'. The code is working fine when sending one file in each post request. **But, how can I update the code below to send multiple files in one post request where all the files belong to the same 'student_id'**?

```
       try{  
            File textFile2 = new File("info.txt");  

         URL url = new URL("htttp://wwww.students.com");
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();         
         urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
         urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);   


        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);          
        OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);

        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"student_id\"").append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
        writer.append(CRLF).append("25").append(CRLF).flush();


        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"newfile\"; filename=\"" + textFile2.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF); // Text file itself must be saved in this charset!
        writer.append(CRLF).flush();                                                            
        Files.copy(textFile2.toPath(), output);//copies all bytes in  a file to the output stream 
        output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
        writer.append(CRLF).flush();

        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
        InputStream responseStream; 

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried to add 'multiple' with the parameter in 'newfile' but it is not working

```
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"newfile\" multiple; filename=\"" + textFile2.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF); // Text file itself must be saved in this charset!
    writer.append(CRLF).flush();                                                            
    Files.copy(textFile2.toPath(), output);//copies all bytes in  a file to the output stream 
    output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
    writer.append(CRLF).flush();

    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
```

Comment: Mixing a wrapper of an OutputStream with direct writes to the original OutputStream is asking for problems.  Use a PrintStream instead of a PrintWriter, and pass that PrintStream to Files.copy.  Once you wrap an OutputStream in something like PrintStream or OutputStreamWriter, you should not refer to that OutputStream again.

Comment: If it is possible, can you please show me an example of what you are suggesting

Comment: Change `PrintWriter writer = …` to `PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(output, true, charset);`.  Change your Files.copy statement to `Files.copy(textFile2.toPath(), writer);`.  That way, all lines are writing to the exactly the same output object.  Remove your call to output.flush().  And remember to call `writer.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are trying to post a `multipart/form-data` request with 1 *form field* with `name` parameter of `student_id` and multiple *file part* to upload files.

You can send multiple filesby supplying each file in a separate part but all with the same `name` parameter.

For example, you can upload a file of `textFile1` by sending the first *file part* with `name` parameter of `newfile`:

```
writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"newfile\"; filename=\"" + textFile1.getName()+ "\"").append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
writer.append(CRLF);
writer.flush();

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(textFile1);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
outputStream.flush();
inputStream.close();

writer.append(CRLF);
writer.flush();
```

Then, you can upload another file of `textFile2` by sending *file part* with same `name` parameter of `newfile`:

```
writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"newfile\"; filename=\"" + textFile2.getName()+ "\"").append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
writer.append(CRLF);
writer.flush();

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(textFile2);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
outputStream.flush();
inputStream.close();

writer.append(CRLF);
writer.flush();
```

As you can see, the code are almost the same except the file to upload. It is recommend to put the code into a method and call it to send each *file part*.

Comment: I am trying to send to post multipart/form-data request with 2 form field named as student_id and the second field is the 'newfile' which holds the file.Therefore, I cann't change the name field 'newfile' in the form

Comment: @ryh12 I updated it with example. Please see whether it can help

Comment: I tried your method but it is adding the first file only and ignoring the other file @Wilson

Comment: @ry12 It should work if the sever side support upload multiple files for one form field with separated file part. I suspect the server side use a older method to parse request with a nested "multipart/mixed" part or it do not support upload multiple files for one form field. Is server side implemented by you? Do you know what method the server side support?